# Evaluating the critic score in WGANs

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I've been trying to train a WGAN for the last couple of days with gradient penalty involved. I took the gradient penalty code off of a github tensorflow implementation by ChengBinJin.

With a normal DCGAN you'd be able to tell what the accuracy of the discriminator is at any point, cause it's trying to learn logits you can throw into a sigmoid function. So if I threw in real images, the accuracy would be close to a 100%, very straight-forward.

However with respect to WGANs, the discriminator is now a critic and it outputs a score instead which isn't really translatable into accuracy as far as I can tell. Right now I'm at 3000 iterations and the mean score for real images is at -59,000. So how would one go about trying to gauge accuracy from this score?

Answer (score 1):

Not at all. The Wasserstein Critic is mean independant as it is written as f(x) - f(y). So So a function g(x) = f(x) + b has the same Wasserstein distance. E.g. g(x) - g(y) = f(x) + b - f(y) - b = f(x) - f(y).

So the mean gives you no information. What does give you information is the difference between the means of the real and the fake images, e.g. the Wasserstein distance. The smaller the better.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I suppose that's the best way to go about it. However I was working on it today and the distance keeps going up (with dips at certain points) while generating subpar MNIST digits. My DCGAN results look better than this. I would assume it should be going towards zero, right?                                                             Also as an aside, would it interfere with the WGAN training to add a separate softmax layer at the end of the discriminator along with the single score neuron?